# Styling division between div

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```
<section class="background">
 <div class="container>

 </div>
</section>

<section>
 <div class="container>

 </div>
</section>
```

The first section has an image as background

I would like to stylize the division between the divs, according to the image:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to get started? Thanks

Comment: you can let section2 cover the foot of section1, and section2 with a png as background

Answer (score 0):

You could create a container for your two sections, apply a background color to it, and then add margin-botton to the first section. There's no way to target the division between two divs directly. Below is the code; expand the snipped to see it running.

```css
.background {
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
}
.container-1 {
  background: red;
}
.container-2 {
  background: green;
}
.section-container {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='section-container'>
  
  <section class="background">
   <div class="container-1">
   First section
   </div>
  </section>

  <section>
   <div class="container-2">
   Second section.
   </div>
  </section>
  
</div>
```

Comment: And is it even possible to make the "inverted triangle"?

Comment: Yes, see my proposal

Answer (score 0):

You may use this as a starting point.

```css
.arrow, .arrow2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
}
.arrow {
   z-index:20;
   border-left: 33px solid transparent;
   border-right: 33px solid transparent; 
   border-top:40px solid yellow;
   margin-left: -3px;
}
.arrow2 {
   z-index:100;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent; 
   border-top:30px solid red; 
}
.bar {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: yellow;
 }
.container-1 {
   background: red;
   height: 80px;
}
.container-2 {
   background: green;
   position: relative;
   height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <section>
   <div class="container-1">
   First section
   </div>
  </section>

  <section>
   <div class="container-2">
       <div class="arrow"></div>
       <div class="arrow2"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
   Second section.
   </div>
  </section>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding a `canvas` block between your first `section` and your second `section`. Then you can "paint" whatever kind of triangle or other shape you want, and change the colors whenever you want. All you'd have to do is make sure that the bottom of the first `section` is aligned with the top of the second `section`, the bottom of the `canvas` is aligned with the top of the second `section`, and that the `canvas` overlaps the first `section`.

```
<section class="background">
   <div class="container>
      ...
   </div>
</section>
<!-- this will act as your section border, style it as you wish -->
<canvas class="triangle">
    ...
</canvas>
<section>
   <div class="container>
      ...
   </div>
</section>
```